# How can use Zuul gateway with Spring boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am trying create a Zuul Api gateway for my microservices. It also has the eureka disovery client.

I am using Spring Boot 3 and Zuul 1.0 starter.

Here is the application Zuul Gateway class.

ZuulGatewayApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;


@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class ZuulGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.manager.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>zuul-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>zuul-gateway</name>
    <description>Zuul gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I am getting the following error while trying to run the application.

```
****************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field optionalArgs in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Zuul hasn't been supported for a while now. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952820/does-zuul-have-any-support-issues-in-springboot-2-7-and-java-11) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100671/nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-boot-web-servlet-error-errorcontroller-ge).